# Get label prediction from Cifar-10 model

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm currently working on the Cifar-10 tutorial of tensorflow. I'd like to change the evaluation such that I can see for each image what the prediction of my model was, and whether it was true/false. I struggle with the first part: if I print the predictions (sess.run([top_k_op])) I get true/false values which I assume are whether the prediction was correct or not. However, if I try to print the actual prediction (I tried so far to print the logits, and print the top_k_op tensor), I get some numbers or values, but nothing that looks like the labels. What do I have to change about my code to actually see the labels that my model predicted?

Answer (score 0):

You want to evaluate first the `logits`. This is a probability distribution over your classes out of your network. The index of the tensor with the higher value will give you the most likely class for your label.

you can use [tf.argmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#argmax) to get the index and then use the index in your labels to print it out

```
print labels[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out an answer by looking [here](https://github.com/jkschin/svhn)

In svhn.py, at line 116 the predicted label is printed: `print (step, int(test_labels[0]))`

I did it in a clear way by using:

```
classification = sess.run(top_k_predict_op)
print (step, int(test_labels[0]))
print "network predicted:", classification[0], "for real label:", test_labels
```

Be sure that you are predicting on 24*24 images, in case you trained your model with the original version of the TensorFlow CIFAR-10 model.